# Is it possible to connect to HBase from an SpringDM application? Getting missing constraint for com.sun.security.auth!

Tags: hadoop, osgi, hbase, springsource-dm-server

I'm building a webapp that should connect to a HBase datastore. Since there is no OSGi'fied version (that I'm aware of) of the *hadoop-core* and *hbase* jars I was planning on using BND to generate these. When I provision them however, the following pops up:
*Missing Constraint: Import-Package: com.sun.security.auth; version="0.0.0"*

Any ideas on where to find a (OSGi'fied) jar for this package? Is it überhaupt possible to connect to HBase from a SpringDM app? Apart from DataNucleus I haven't seen anybody doing so...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Kind regards,

Niels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that your bundle wants to import a package (when you take a look at its manifest, you will see an `Import-Package` statements, which will include `com.sun.security.auth`). This is a class that is provided by the Sun Java VM, but *not* exported by default from the OSGi framework bundle (bundle 0); this is because is is not part of the Java class library, but is Sun-specific.

If you really need this class, you can use a framework property to make the system bundle export it; you will need a statement like

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=com.sun.security.auth
```

The exact way in which you can give this directive, depends on the framework launcher you use.